# Combining 2 columns in a multi-index multi-column dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following Dataframe, How can I add A+B to create a new column called "A+B_new" and C to be a new column called "C_new".
I am using the latest 3.10 or 3.11 python and JupyterLab.

Starting DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
data =  {('2022/10', 'A'): {'ABC': 7, 'CDE': 4, 'FGH': 7},
         ('2022/10', 'B'): {'ABC': 3, 'CDE': 3, 'FGH': 6},
         ('2022/10', 'C'): {'ABC': 6, 'CDE': 4, 'FGH': 5},
         ('2022/11', 'A'): {'ABC': 2, 'CDE': 5, 'FGH': 7},
         ('2022/11', 'B'): {'ABC': 5, 'CDE': 8, 'FGH': 4},
         ('2022/11', 'C'): {'ABC': 9, 'CDE': 3, 'FGH': 3},
         ('2022/12', 'A'): {'ABC': 2, 'CDE': 4, 'FGH': 5},
         ('2022/12', 'B'): {'ABC': 6, 'CDE': 7, 'FGH': 4},
         ('2022/12', 'C'): {'ABC': 3, 'CDE': 8, 'FGH': 5 }}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['ABC','CDE','FGH'])
df
```

And the Resulting DataFrame should be:

```
data2 =  {('2022/10', 'A+B_new'): {'ABC': 10, 'CDE': 7, 'FGH': 13},
          ('2022/10', 'C_new'): {'ABC': 6, 'CDE': 4, 'FGH': 5},
          ('2022/11', 'A+B_new'): {'ABC': 7, 'CDE': 13, 'FGH': 11},
          ('2022/11', 'C_new'): {'ABC': 6, 'CDE': 4, 'FGH': 5},
          ('2022/12', 'A+B_new'): {'ABC': 8, 'CDE': 11, 'FGH': 9},
          ('2022/12', 'C_new'): {'ABC': 6, 'CDE': 4, 'FGH': 5}}
 
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=['ABC','CDE','FGH'])
df_result
```

Comment: Hi John! Have you seen this before? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557 Please make your question reproducible by including the dataframes themselves, not pictures of them

Comment: Thank you. I am now researching how to create the above the dataframe. Any help !

Comment: is the original file an excel file?

Comment: because you said in the question "I have the following Dataframe", but the picture is of a spreadsheet

Comment: Yes, I do. How can I export a dataframe so I could build one with random data?

Comment: I don't follow. Regardless, I can't help you if you don't provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with working with multi-indexed data, but I found a decent way to calculate `A+B_new` at least:

```
Idx = pd.IndexSlice

a_b_new = df.loc[:, Idx[:,['A','B']]].groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
a_b_new
```

```
     2022/10  2022/11  2022/12
ABC       10        7        8
CDE        7       13       11
FGH       13       11        9
```

Here's a kludgy way (IMHO) to use the same idea to get what you want:

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(
    lambda d: pd.DataFrame({
        'A+B_new': d.loc[:, Idx[:,['A','B']]].sum(axis=1),
        'C_new': d.droplevel(0, axis=1)['C']}))
```

```
    2022/10       2022/11       2022/12      
    A+B_new C_new A+B_new C_new A+B_new C_new
ABC      10     6       7     9       8     3
CDE       7     4      13     3      11     8
FGH      13     5      11     3       9     5
```

Comment: Amazing. now that is a level of pandas jugglery that I will never achieve. Wow. I need to digest this. Thank you very much.